# Bootstrap Tooltip Not showing on SVG Hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-svg

Can you please take a look at this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/aj6BX/1/) and let me know why the bootstrap tooltip not showing on this svg?

Here is the code I have

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200  200" xml:space="preserve">
   <polygon  class="firststar" points="64.385,54.267 56.951,50.769 49.854,54.911 50.884,46.76 44.752,41.291 52.823,39.751 56.129,32.229 60.087,39.429 
68.262,40.249 62.639,46.239 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

and

I am using this jquery function

```
$('.firststar').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is because by default it inserts the dynamically generated tooltip div in the svg which makes browser not to render it. Instead use the `container` property in the options to set the container where the boostrap generated div needs to be placed. See an ex below:

```
$('.firststar').tooltip({title:'sometitle', container:'body'});
```

Container can be any non svg element container. say in your case `.well` so you would write it as

```
$('.firststar').tooltip({title:'sometitle', container:'.well'});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eGyWV/)

See [tooltip options](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

Comment: Thanks PSL, so we always have to pass the options like container:'body' am I right?

Comment: @MonaCoder You are welcome. You could provide any other container too. like `$('.firststar').tooltip({title:'some title', container:'.well'});`